# Making a function undefined when called by url

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

Using Codeigniter, i call a public function[of my controller] from the url which is basically normal behavior of the framework. I'm passing 3 parameters as `$a, $b, $c` and as the function gets executed, it checks the parameters and goes according to it. Now, the problem is i do not want my function to be called from the url, when it is called it should go to 404 page.
i do know that this can be achieved by adding `private` or `protected`, but the real problem is it should be accessed only through one of my own other functions and not by direct url.
Any solutions are welcome.

HTTP route block works. But when i pass parameters, the function gets executed which is a security problem. Any idea how to block access?

Comment: What's the problem with private or protected?

Comment: Basically, it is restricting the access to url, which should not happen. If the parameters are not passed when the function is called, it should go to 404. it should not even enter the function.

Comment: Whatever you just told, is possible through private scope. Implementation is wrong perhaps. You need to show codes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use routing to block any http traffic to that controller/method and redirect to the 404 page.

In your `routes.php` file in the config folder, add the following

```
$route['controller/private_method'] = '{your 404 controller}';
$route['controller/private_method/(:any)'] = '{404 controller}';
```

The second rule caters for any number of parameters.

Comment: Hey, it did help, thanks. It does block the HTTP traffic, But when i pass the parameters say like this `http://mysite.com/controller/private_method/shshsh/ajdhdh/` it would load the function, which is again a vulnerability. any idea?

Comment: That was cool. But that completely blocked the access from HTTP. 
i want to be able to call this function only when called from a other particular function only.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you pass a `hidden secret variable` to `identify` that you are `calling this function` and it isn't getting called from `URL`.

Comment: Exactly, so say i pass the id as parameter. So even if the id doesn't get passed with the function, still the function executes which should not happen.

Comment: How can this happen, you would be doing some mistake in validating that the id is passed or not. Can you show the code?

Comment: According to c or c++ oops, if you dont pass parameters, the function throws error saying paramters is 0 and it doesn't get executed. i want the same functionality here.